# HttpWebResponse- Avoid save file dialog

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, stream

I have following method to read a response from remote server

```
public string GetResponse()
        {
            string url = "http://remoteserver.com/getdata.jsp?id=515";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
            StreamReader loResponseStream = new
            StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc);

            string ServerResponse = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

            loResponseStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            return ServerResponse;
        }
```

In my `actionresult` I am calling this method as follows

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  string resp= GetResponse();

   return View();
}
```

Now instead of showing me view browser is prompting me to save file. how to avoid that and show view as normal

Comment: you need to add `Response.ContentType = "text/HTML"` ;

Comment: this is giving me error This property is not implemented by this class

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom action result

```
public class TextActionResult : ActionResult
{
    readonly string _response;

    public TextActionResult() { }

    public TextActionResult(string response)
    {
        _response = response;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html";  //text/plain?
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(_response);
        //you may want further tweaks here
        }
}
```

and your controller

```
public TextActionResult Index()
{
   string resp= GetResponse();
   return new TextActionResult (resp);
}
```

ps - take a look at using WebClient, e.g.

```
string url = "http://remoteserver.com/getdata.jsp?id=515";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
     var result = client.DownloadString(url);
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string resp= GetResponse();

    return Content(resp);
}
```